# Failure 1:Syntax error

Tags: android, sqlite

I am a new in SQLite.  I am trying to use SQLite in Android. But I am facing this kind of error when I run it.

Error:

> Failure 1 (near "tableuserInfoTable": syntax error) on 0x14d2c8 when preparing `'create tableuserInfoTable(_id integer primary key name text not nullemailtext not nullpasswordtext not nulltimetext not null);'`.

Code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME="data";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;

    public static final String USER_TABLE="userTable";
    public static final String C_ID="_id";
    public static final String USER="name";
    public static final String EMAIL="email";
    public static final String PASSWORD="password";
    public static final String TIME="time";

    public final String createDB="create table"+USER_TABLE+"("+C_ID+" integer primary key "
                             +USER+" text not null"  +EMAIL+ "text not null" +PASSWORD+ "text not null" 
                             +TIME+ "text not null);";

    public DBHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL(createDB);
    }


@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (newVersion > oldVersion) {
        Log.w("MyAppTag","Updating database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + " .Existing data will be lost.");
  db.execSQL("drop table if exists"+USER_TABLE);
  onCreate(db);
}
}  
 }
```

I went over almost every single example from SO,but I couldn't figure that out.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
public final String createDB="create table "+USER_TABLE+"("
                         +C_ID+" integer primary key, "
                         +USER+" text not null,"  
                         +EMAIL+ " text not null," 
                         +PASSWORD+ " text not null," 
                         +TIME+ " text not null);";
```

A couple of errors:
 - You are missing a space between table and the tableName;
 - You are missing the commas at the end of the columns, 
 - You are also missing spaces between the column names and the data types:

You should always log your query and try to run it in the database directly. The errors will become clear very quickly.

Answer (score 3):

There is no comma in your query, and you missed some spaces.

Try :

```
public final String createDB="create table "+USER_TABLE+"("+C_ID+" integer primary key, "
                         +USER+" text not null,"  +EMAIL+ " text not null, " +PASSWORD+ " text not null," 
                         +TIME+ " text not null);";
```

Comment: There's also no space between the "create table" and the name of the table.

Comment: Thanks for having noticied it. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Failure 1 (near "tableuserInfoTable": syntax error) on 0x14d2c8 when preparing `create tableuserInfoTable(_id integer primary key name text not nullemailtext not nullpasswordtext not nulltimetext not null);`.

- This type of error is missing tablename (If wrong) or comma and space or datatype is missing.

**Solution**
If your table name is `tableuserInfoTable` then starting query:

```
create table tableuserInfoTable(
_id integer primary key name text not null,
email text not null, 
password text not null,
time text not null);
```