# Android: SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed

Tags: android, sqlite, constraints

I checked other examples in SO and I searched a lot, nothing is working for me. The database file is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20444838/failure-1syntax-error) (after suggested edit).

**Error**

```
E/Database(274): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
E/Database(274):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_execute(Native Method)
E/Database(274):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.execute(SQLiteStatement.java:55)
E/Database(274):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1549)
E/Database(274):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1410)
E/Database(274):    at com.example.nycgasstationhunter.userRegister$2.onClick(userRegister.java:51)
E/Database(274):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
E/Database(274):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
E/Database(274):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
E/Database(274):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/Database(274):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/Database(274):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
E/Database(274):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/Database(274):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/Database(274):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
E/Database(274):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
E/Database(274):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Code**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class userRegister extends Activity{
//database
SQLiteDatabase db;
DBHelper dbhelper;
Context ourContext;
ContentValues cv;

 public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_register);

//database  
 dbhelper=new DBHelper(this);
 db=dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
 cv=new ContentValues();
//editText
final EditText userEdit=(EditText)  findViewById(R.id.userEdit);
final EditText emailEdit=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailEdit);
final EditText passwordEdit=(EditText)  findViewById(R.id.passwordEdit);
final EditText retypePassEdit=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.retypePassEdit);
//Register button
    Button regButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.regButton);
      regButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
    //string
    final String userName=userEdit.getText().toString();
    final String emailAddress=emailEdit.getText().toString();
    final String password=passwordEdit.getText().toString();
    final String retypePassword=retypePassEdit.getText().toString();

         if (userName.length()!=0){
            if (emailAddress.length()!=0){
              if (password.length()!=0){
                 if (retypePassword.equals(password)){
                   //save in DB
                    cv.put(DBHelper.USER, userName);
                    cv.put(DBHelper.EMAIL,emailAddress);
                    cv.put(DBHelper.PASSWORD, retypePassword); 

                    db.insert(DBHelper.USER_TABLE, null, cv);

                    Intent intent = new Intent (userRegister.this,Profile.class);    
                     startActivity(intent);
               }
                 else 
                     Toast.makeText(userRegister.this,"Password mismatch", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
            }
              else 
                     Toast.makeText(userRegister.this,"Invalid password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
            else 
                 Toast.makeText(userRegister.this,"Invalid email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
         else 
             Toast.makeText(userRegister.this,"Invalid user name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
});
}
}
```

When I insert information and press regButton, it sends me to Profile activity. There is no information being saved in database. I don't understand the error in LogCat and how can I solve that? Why there is nothing in database?  (I am using [SQLite Database Browser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/?source=dlp) to check data.)  Thank you

Comment: Please add your DBHelper code / database schema.

Comment: @laalto --The database (with suggested edit):http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20444838/failure-1syntax-error

Comment: Please add the table creation part in this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error `SQLiteConstraintException` indicates that an integrity constraint was violated.

From your Create Table SQL command I think the first problem is your primary key. It should be declare as `autoincrement`

Change String createDB:

```
public final String createDB="create table "+USER_TABLE+"("
                    + C_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
                    + USER + " text not null,"  
                    + EMAIL + " text not null," 
                    + PASSWORD + " text not null," 
                    + TIME + " text not null);";
```

Also, all fields are declared `not null`, you should test if `retypePassword` is not null and you must set a value to field TIME.

**EDIT**

In order the `autoincrement` take effect, the database version value need to be incremented.
In DBHelper class change `DATABASE_VERSION=1;` to `DATABASE_VERSION=2;`

Comment: Same error.But if I change like this: **code**    try {
            db.insertOrThrow(DBHelper.USER_TABLE, null, cv);
      } catch (SQLException ex) {
            // do something with ex or nothing
      }          errror goes away but nothing in Database

Comment: I forgot to mention one thing! Please see the edit to my answer.

Comment: No luck. I got a force close. Problem with upgrade ---Public void onUpgrade(){}                       **Error**                               I/Database(275): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = near "existsuserInfoTable": syntax error                                      E/AndroidRuntime(294): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myappp/com.example.myapp.userRegister}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "existsuserInfoTable": syntax error: drop table if existsuserInfoTable ...so on

Comment: I fixed the problem for now. I changed the emulator. Now it works and I can see the data. I didn't change the DATABASE_VERSION and removed Log.w() from public void onUpgrade(){} in DBHelper class.  Please let me know that if this is a right path or not. Any advice will be welcomed. Thank you

Comment: As you do when write any frase in english or in any language you should put spaces between words. A space is need between the sentence `drop table if exists` and table name, add a space after word "exist" in `db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + USER_TABLE);`. When you change the emulator a new database was created with the changed `createDB` string that's why now works.

Comment: If someone's answer solved your problem, you might want to accept it as the answer using the big checkbox.

Answer (score 2):

If the database schema is as follows as you mention in comments (from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20444838/failure-1syntax-error))...

```
public final String createDB="create table "+USER_TABLE+"("
                     +C_ID+" integer primary key, "
                     +USER+" text not null,"  
                     +EMAIL+ " text not null," 
                     +PASSWORD+ " text not null," 
                     +TIME+ " text not null);";
```

... then you have not specified a value for the `TIME` column which has the `not null` constraint.

Some options:

- Add a `TIME` value to the `ContentValues` before `insert()`.
- Change the schema and provide a suitable default such as

  ```
  TIME + " text not null default current_timestamp"
  ```

  As always, when changing the database schema, remove the old database so that `onCreate()` gets called with the new code (clear app data or just uninstall the app).

Answer (score 0):

In my case I made two HTTP-requests and got two lists. Then wrote them to two tables. But first in a child table and then in parent. Strange, but a problem appeared on Android 4.4.2, but not on Android 5.0.